# How to loop iterate single value with array?

Tags: javascript, airtable

How do I achieve this in Javascript?

My problem is e.g.
templateMonth (string/single line value); templateName (array value)

```
const a = 2022-01
const b = ['HD-HD1460', 'HD-WHITE', 'HD-YHS']
```

My desired output is

```
2022-01; HD-HD1460 
2022-01; HD-WHITE
2022-01; HD-YHS
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Answer (score 3):

Just loop through all elements in `b` and simply output `a` in the loop. The loop has access to variables outside of it.

Your `a` should also be changed to a string, since `2022-01` will substract 1 from 2022, probably not what you intended.

```js
const a = '2022-01'
const b = ['HD-HD1460', 'HD-WHITE', 'HD-YHS']

b.forEach(item=>console.log(`${a}; ${item}`))
```

Consider searching the internet for JavaScript documentation and tutorials and make a first effort yourself.

Comment: Fix that `forEach` and you get a vote.

Comment: Oh I fixed it for Usama, wanted to make this a snippet as well :)

Comment: Sorry, I just realised mine is an object. So now I want iterate over a specific field in an object.

Answer (score 1):

you can combine them into an array of object or if you needjust the console.log you can do as @Usama Masood suggested

```js
const a = '2022-01'
const b = ['HD-HD1460', 'HD-WHITE', 'HD-YHS']

const combined = b.map(name => ({date: a, name}))

combined.forEach(c => console.log(`${c.date} ${c.name}`))

//or simply

b.forEach(i => console.log(`${a} ${i}`))
```